# Word for a person whose vocabulary is very limited (as in like 100 words)

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

Is there a word for a person who hardly knows English as in like 100 words, but pretends they are an English major?

Comment: Do they talk *gibberish*?

Comment: You can't pretend you're an English major with 100 words under your belt. You can't even pretend to be a four-year old.

Comment: They'd be called a *liar*, a *fraud* or if they half-believe it themselves *deluded* or perhaps "a Walter Mitty". Of course, they'd be doing that lying in a language other than English, unless "I am an English major" happened to be among those 100. Just like I could say right here "I am a Danish major", though I couldn't say it in Danish, though I'd reckon I might have a bit over 100 Danish words.

Comment: Spy. Badly trained spy.

Comment: Is this question about the limited vocabulary specifically or is it about the exaggeration of ability?

Comment: @Edwin I believe you mean "Bad train spy".

Comment: @corsiKa You mean a nasty sleeper?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that person is being ***pretentious***.

[Pretentious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pretentious) : *a. making usually unjustified or excessive claims*

*b. expressive of affected, unwarranted, or exaggerated importance, worth, or stature*

**Eg:** He could barely speak English, while he claimed to be an English major. What a pretentious <"expletive of choice">!

Comment: Pretentious is rarely used the way it is defined in 1). If you were trying to insult somebody's vocabulary by calling them "pretentious" 9/10 people would misinterpret what you are trying to say.

Comment: And for exactly the reason, I have been generous enough to provide an example :)

Comment: Haha fair enough! Have a +1

Answer (score 1):

They are usually called

### **phonies**.

Answer (score 0):

They are an *[imposter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/imposter)*

> a person who deceives others, esp by assuming a false identity; charlatan

although they would not know that word (or *charlatan*).